# open a vertical door with an arduino

Tags: arduino, motor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a motor to open doors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32374/using-a-motor-to-open-doors)

iv attached a picture of what im trying to do. Open a vertical door on my wood work project.

i just want to know what methods i could use to do this;
 - like useing a servo and a rod
 - Something else
thanks
[image: this is a picof what im trying to acheve]